# Oxidizing property of permanganate

Tags: oxidation-state

If permanganate is a stronger and efficient oxidizing agent in acidic medium than alkaline medium.

Then why does it oxidise iodide(-1) to iodate(+5) in alkaline medium but iodide to iodine(0) in acidic medium ?

Comment: Iodate is a stronger oxidizing agent in acidic medium than alkaline medium.

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iodate ion needs $\ce{H+}$ to give a reducing half-equation with electrons, in an equation like : $$\ce{6 e- + IO3^- + 6 H+ -> I^- + 3 H2O}$$ If no $\ce{H+}$ are available, the iodate ion may react with $\ce{H2O}$ instead, but it will produce $\ce{OH-}$ ions according to the half-equation $$\ce{6 e- + IO3^- + 3 H2O -> I- + 6 OH-}$$ but the ion $\ce{IO3^-}$ cannot react with electrons in basic medium. This basic reaction would imply a collision of three negative species : $\ce{OH-}$, $\ce{IO3^-}$ and electrons. Three negative entities would repel one another : the whole process is hardly possible.

Comment: Wouldn't that imply permanganate oxidizes iodide to iodate in acidic medium?

Comment: No ! Permanganate oxidizes iodide ions $\ce{I-}$ to iodine $\ce{I2}$. It cannot oxidize the iodine atom to a higher oxidation number. If it would succeed, the following reaction would immediately take place and reduce iodate ions to iodine : $$\ce{2 IO3^- + 10 I^- + 12 H+ -> 6 I2 + 6 H2O}$$

Comment: Oh.! Got it. thanks.